# Why do interrupts need to be turned off when inside other interrupt code?

Tags: exceptions

Simple question that will help me understand my OS class... thanks!

Basically, why is it unsafe to have an interrupt within an interrupt? (or exception within exception)

Comment: If this is for a class, you'd better talk to your professor.  Nested interrupts (higher-priority interrupts interrupting lower-priority interrupt handlers) are done all the time in the real world.  They do require some planning, and careful design in hardware and software.  Your professor (or TA, or textbook) may have been thinking about the old IBM PC interrupt controller, which had some real deficiencies compared to other hardware at that time.

Comment: I agree. This question is asking why something is so that is not always so. A better question would be: **When** is it unsafe ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> There are two types of interaction between the CPU and the rest of the
>   computer's hardware. The first type is when the CPU gives orders to
>   the hardware, the other is when the hardware needs to tell the CPU
>   something. The second, called interrupts, is much harder to implement
>   because it has to be dealt with when convenient for the hardware, not
>   the CPU. Hardware devices typically have a very small amount of RAM,
>   and if you don't read their information when available, it is lost.
>
> Under Linux, hardware interrupts are called IRQ's (InterruptRe
>   quests). There are two types of IRQ's, short and long. A short IRQ
>   is one which is expected to take a very short period of time, during
>   which the rest of the machine will be blocked and no other interrupts
>   will be handled. A long IRQ is one which can take longer, and during
>   which other interrupts may occur **(but not interrupts from the same
>   device)**. If at all possible, it's better to declare an interrupt
>   handler to be long.
>
> When the CPU receives an interrupt, it stops whatever it's doing
>   (unless it's processing a more important interrupt, in which case it
>   will deal with this one only when the more important one is done),
>   saves certain parameters on the stack and calls the interrupt handler.
>   This means that **certain things are not allowed in the interrupt
>   handler itself, because the system is in an unknown state.**
>
> The solution to this problem is for the interrupt handler to do what
>   needs to be done immediately, usually read something from the hardware
>   or send something to the hardware, and then schedule the handling of
>   the new information at a later time (this is called the "bottom half")
>   and return. The kernel is then guaranteed to call the bottom half as
>   soon as possible -- and when it does, everything allowed in kernel
>   modules will be allowed.

http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x1256.html

Answer (score 6):

The general issue is that an interrupt handler will typically manipulate data structures and it would corrupt those data structures if that same code was reentered in mid-update.  However, there are many ways to organize interrupt systems and many of those ways allow nested interrupts at different priority levels.  Interrupt controllers can mask off interrupts that have not yet been acknowledged by the interrupt handling code, so it is too broad a statement to say that it is "unsafe to have an interrupt within an interrupt".  It will depend on the design of the interrupt controller (hardware) and the interrupt handlers (software), as well as the characteristics of the interrupting device and the meaning of the interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Many systems use level-sensitive interrupts.  This means that any time a particular interrupt is enabled and the interrupt is active, it will call the handler associated with that interrupt at the first opportunity (generally whenever it finishes an instruction).  If an interrupt were left enabled while it was serviced, then as soon as the processor finished processing the first instruction of an interrupt handler, it would immediately perform another call to that same interrupt handler, execute one instruction, then perform another call to that handler, etc. and would bomb the stack without ever getting a chance to do any useful work in the interrupt handler.

While it may be possible to have a system process an interrupt as a one-off response and ignore the interrupt line until the next time the condition arises, it can be hard to make such designs work reliably if interrupts may become active while they are being serviced (e.g. a serial port receives a character while the CPU is processing an earlier character).  An advantage of level-sensitive interrupts is that if an interrupt-worthy stimulus arrives between the time its handler has processed the previous one from that source and the time it returns, the act of returning will re-enable the interrupt and will cause the handler to be re-executed to handle the new stimulus.  The system may lock of if an interrupt is never able to satisfy the device that's requesting an interrupt, but such problems are often easier to debug than problems that can result when using edge-triggered interrupts if the CPU can't respond to a stimulus precisely when it occurs and consequently ends up never responding to it at all.